# parse key: value pair with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have a service which I hit gives response back in below format `key: value` and I want to extract key/value pair from it and load it in a map.

```
state: UP flag: 9 time: 02:29:09.111782 highest_id: num_users: 0 num_records: 0
```

So I am using regular expression to parse this and extract key/value pair from it.

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\S+)\\s*:\\s*(\\S+)");

String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(response);
while (m.find()) {
    String key = m.group(1).trim();
    String value = m.group(2).trim();
    // load key/value in a map
}
```

Now problem with above regular expression is for above data - it takes `highest_id` as key but it takes `num_users: 0` as it's value which is wrong. In this case it should take `highest_id` as key and value should be empty string or null since there is nothing after `:` for that key and next key should be `num_users` and value should be `0`.

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: This data format is terrible. Any chance you can change it?

Comment: Right now, we cannot change this. It's been running it from a while so that's why I am using regex to do parse it.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use a regex to parse it.  You could split it on whitespace.  Then iterating through the tokens, expect the first to end with a ':'.  When a token ends with a ':' look ahead at the next one.  If it does not end with ':' then it is the value, otherwise the value is absent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex to get each pair:

### `(\S+):\s(\S*)(?:\b(?!:)|$)`

It searches for a key, then a colon and a space, then zero or more characters if they don't end in a colon or if it's the end of the line.

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/gY8cD4/4)

Use it like this:

```
Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\S+):\\s(\\S*)(?:\\b(?!:)|$)").matcher(inputText);
while (m.find()) {
    pairs.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

If a value is missing it will put an empty string.

[Ideone Tested](https://ideone.com/daN3Wl)

Comment: I have similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946752/parse-a-string-in-a-particular-format). See if you can help me out

Comment: Yes, sorry. I looked at the question you linked, and it looks like the best solution there is to not use regex. It's possible though. Are you still looking for an answer to it?

Comment: Ohh I see.. Yeah I am still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex with word boundary and negative lookahead:

```
(\w+):\s(\S*\b(?!:))
```

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):\\s(\\S*\\b(?!:))");
```

`\b` (word boundary) and negative lookahead `(?!:)` is to make sure you don't match next key as current key's value which is empty.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fI7uM6/2)

Comment: How do I use this in a  `Pattern.compile`? If I copy this as it is then I get compile errors as `Invalid escape sequence`?

Comment: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):\\s(\\S*\\b(?!:))");`

Comment: It's funny. I didn't ever see your answer beforehand but I have something very similar. Although I posted the exact Java code to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should match the whole string without gaps. If there are gaps something went wrong (you can sum the lengths of group(0) and compare it to the string length). If there is a 2nd group it needs to be trimmed. [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/fI7uM6/3)

```
Pattern.compile("([a-z_]+): +([0-9A-Za-z.:]*[0-9A-Za-z.](?: +|$))?");
```

Comment: Aren't you here long enough by now? Why don't you add an explanation to this answer to "Make This Answer Great™" ?

Comment: Well, that answer is currently in review. It'll get deleted eventually, if you don't add any details. You know how that works, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead of either the next key or the end of the string.

Example:

```
String response = "state: UP flag: 9 time: 02:29:09.111782 highest_id: num_users: 0 num_records: 0";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z_]+:)(.*?)(?=[a-z_]+:|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(response);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " -> " + m.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
state: ->  UP 
flag: ->  9 
time: ->  02:29:09.111782 
highest_id: ->  
num_users: ->  0 
num_records: ->  0
```

Breakdown:

- `([a-z_]+:)` Current key
- `(.*?)` Value, can be empty, non-greedy
- `(?=[a-z_]+:|$)` Lookahead of either next key or end of line

Of course, this could break if the values can look "key-like" as well...

Comment: key can also have `_` and other characters as well and value can also be any string with any characters

Comment: @user1950349 I included `_` in the pattern. For other characters: Should be no problem to extend the "key" pattern with those, as long as they do not interfere with e.g. the date value. But as less restricted keys and values are, the harder it will be to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following regex:

```
(\s*(\S+)\s*:)(\s*\w*(\s+|$))(?!(:))
```

It uses a negative look-ahead `?!(:)` to match the previous defined regex only, when it is not followed by a colon ":" character.

`(\s*(\S+)\s*:)` matches the key

`(\s*\w*(\s+|$))` matches the value, which is either followed by a space or by the end of line

`(?!(:))` matches the previous defined regex only when it is not directly followed by a colon character.

You could, for example, use this site: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to verify which part of the string belongs to which group.

An alternative way to using regex is splitting the string by whitespaces, and then going through the resulting array like: uneven index is key, even index is value ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"] etc. This, of course, works only when your key or values do not contain whitespaces themselves. But then the regexes probably wouldn't work either.