# Parse a string in a particular format

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have a response String as shown below which I need to parse it and store it my class. Format is shown below:

- task name followed by this dotted line `-------------`  which is also fixed
- and then just below `key:value` pair. It can have many key value pair

Below is the response string.

```
abc-------------
Load:79008
Peak:4932152

def-------------
Load:79008
Peak:4932216

ghi-------------
Load:79008
Peak:4874588

pqr-------------
Load:79008
Peak:4874748
```

Below is my class:

```
public class NameMetrics {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> metrics;

    // setters and getters

}
```

In the above class, `name` should be `abc` and `metrics` map should have `Load` as the key and `79008` as the value and same with other key:value pairs. I was thinking to use regex but not sure whether I can use regex here.

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\S+):\\s*(\\S*)(?:\\b(?!:)|$)");

String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
// here response will have above string.
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Regex is not needed, just iterate input line by line

Comment: Read lines. Skip blank lines. If `line.indexOf(':')` returns -1, you have a "header" line, otherwise you have a key:value pair, so `substring()` the key and value. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(...???...);
NameMetrics current = null;
List<NameMetrics> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
  String s = reader.readLine();
  if (s == null) {
    break;  // end reached
  }
  if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
    continue;  // Skip empty line
  }
  int cut = s.indexOf(':');
  if (cut == -1) {
    cut = s.indexOf('-');
    if (cut == -1) {
      continue;
    }
    current = new NameMetrics();
    current.setName(s.substring(0, cut));
    result.add(current);
  } else if (current != null) {
    current.setMetrics(s.substring(0, cut), s.substring(cut+1));
  }
}
```